# Resolving multiple instances of a package trying to overwrite a file

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm new to Ubuntu, so please bear with me. I am trying to install some libraries but I keep getting an error. After running `apt-get install -f` I get the same error. It seems like when I try to install the unmet dependencies they overwrite a current file and fail..... so I then tried `autoremove`, which also failed. Ideas?

```
king@king-MS-7640 ~/Downloads/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5 $ sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev libcupsimage2-dev gcc g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
g++ set to manually installed.
gcc is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcupsimage2-dev : Depends: libcupsfilters-dev (>= 1.0~b1) but it is not going to be installed
 libicu-dev : Depends: libicu55 (= 55.1-7ubuntu0.2) but 55.1-7 is to be installed
 libicu55 : Breaks: libicu55:i386 (!= 55.1-7) but 55.1-7ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
 libicu55:i386 : Breaks: libicu55 (!= 55.1-7ubuntu0.2) but 55.1-7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


king@king-MS-7640 ~/Downloads/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5 $ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libicu55
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libicu55
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,659 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 294474 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libicu55:amd64 (55.1-7ubuntu0.2) over (55.1-7) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libicu55/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libicu55:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is a dump of every command I ran in that session

```
854  ./minecraft
  855  minecraft
  856  sudo /opt/minecraft-launcher/minecraft-launcher.sh
  857  sagi minecraft
  858  wget http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libicu52/download
  859  dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
  860  sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
  861  cd Downloads/
  862  sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
  863  ls
  864  wget http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libicu52/download
  865  sudo dpkg -i libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
  866  ls
  867  sagi libicu52
  868  sagi libicu55
  869  sagi libicu-dev
  870  sudo /opt/minecraft-launcher/minecraft-launcher.sh
  871  sagi libicu52
  872  sudo /opt/minecraft-launcher/minecraft-launcher.sh
  873  sagi libicui18n57
  874  sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
  875  sudo apt-get install -y libicu52_52.1-3ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb
  876  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
  877  sudo dpkg -i libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
  878  sudo /opt/minecraft-launcher/minecraft-launcher.sh
  879  wget https://launcher.mojang.com/mc-staging/download/Minecraft_staging.deb
  880  sudo dpkg -i Minecraft_staging.deb 
  881  sudo /opt/minecraft-launcher/minecraft-launcher.sh
  882  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
  883  update
  884  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
  885  sudo apt-get -f install oracle-java8-installer
  886  sagi libicu-dev
  887  apt-get -f install
  888  sudo apt-get -f install
  889  sudo apt-get -f install oracle-java8-installer
  890  sudo apt-get -f install
  891  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
  892  sudo apt-get -f install
  893  update
  894  cd dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5/
  895  xdg-open INSTALL
  896  ./configure
  897  repos misc
  898  ls
  899  cd ../linux_scripts/
  900  ls
  901  git pull
  902  sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
  903  sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2-dev
  904  apt-get install -f
  905  sudo apt-get install -f
  906  sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2-dev
  907  sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
  908  sagi libicu55
  909  sudo /opt/minecraft-launcher/minecraft-launcher.sh
  910  ./configure
  911  make
  912  sudo ./configure
  913  make
  914  make install
  915  history
```

Trying commands based on @Thomas comment below:

```
king@king-MS-7640 ~ $ dpkg -l | grep libicu
ii  libicu-dev:amd64                             55.1-7ubuntu0.2                              amd64        Development files for International Components for Unicode
iU  libicu55:amd64                               55.1-7                                       amd64        International Components for Unicode
iF  libicu55:i386                                55.1-7ubuntu0.2                              i386         International Components for Unicode


king@king-MS-7640 ~ $ sudo apt-get purge libicu-dev
[sudo] password for king: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libicu55 : Breaks: libicu55:i386 (!= 55.1-7) but 55.1-7ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
 libicu55:i386 : Breaks: libicu55 (!= 55.1-7ubuntu0.2) but 55.1-7 is to be installed
 libxml2-dev : Depends: libicu-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


king@king-MS-7640 ~ $ sudo apt-get purge libicu55
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 brltty : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 calibre-bin : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 icu-devtools : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libcamel-1.2-54 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libcdr-0.1-1 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libdee-1.0-4 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libe-book-0.1-1 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libedataserver-1.2-21 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libharfbuzz-icu0 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libicu-dev : Depends: libicu55 (= 55.1-7ubuntu0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libmspub-0.1-1 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5core5a : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libvisio-0.1-1 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 libxml2 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-icu : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Adding output of LS_MESSAGE command:

```
king@king-MS-7640 ~ $ S_MESSAGES=C apt-cache policy libicu55 libicu55:i386 libicu-dev and apt-get install -s libcupsfilters-dev
libicu55:
  Installed: 55.1-7
  Candidate: 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
     55.1-7ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 55.1-7 500
        500 http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libicu55:i386:
  Installed: 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 55.1-7ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     55.1-7 500
        500 http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
libicu-dev:
  Installed: 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
  Candidate: 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
  Version table:
 *** 55.1-7ubuntu0.2 500
        500 http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     55.1-7 500
        500 http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
and:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.2-4.1
  Version table:
     1.2.2-4.1 500
        500 http://mirror.cogentco.com/pub/linux/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
N: Unable to locate package apt-get
N: Unable to locate package install
```

Comment: What did you do to arrive at this state ? Add a ppa ? Install a package from outside the ubuntu repositories ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I added a dump of my history, I hope that helps.... I was attempting to install Minecraft

Comment: You first should try to remove the `libicu*` packages first. It seems you downloaded them manually and installed it with `dpkg`. To find the installed packages use `dpkg -l | grep libicu`, then remove those with `apt-get purge <package-names>. Then do a `apt-get update` and try to install again with `apt-get install ...`. You can search for the packages using `apt-cache search ...`.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the suggestion- I tried it and added the results into my post above

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you using? If not 14.04(Trusty) then why were you downloading & installing trusty packages?

Comment: Assuming you're on 16.04 (xenial),  Open Software & Updates > Updates tab > make sure that the 1st. 2 are enabled, i.e. xenial-security, xenial-updates. The reload sources & run `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Could you please (1) run `sudo apt update` to resynchronise your package list and (2) [edit] your question to include the output of `LS_MESSAGES=C apt-cache policy libicu55 libicu55:i386 libicu-dev` and `apt-get install -s libcupsfilters-dev`? Thanks.

Comment: @doug I  ran the commands you asked- upgrade failed with the same message about unmet dependencies as in my original post. I was installing trusty packages because I was following a fix someone else on SO suggested in another post (it obviously didnt work in my case)

Comment: Maybe you should try this, locate libicu55 in /var/cache/apt/archives/ or download it from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libicu55 Then install it with sudo dpkg --force-overwrite /path/to/packagename  Ex. if it was in your Downloads folder `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite Downloads/libicu55_55.1-7ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb` Then see where you stand

Comment: I got into `/var/cache/apt/archives/` but couldnt see anything in either folder (after launching a session using `su`

Answer (score 0):

there might be a problem with the initial packages you downloaded so perform a `sudo apt-get clean` command which will remove all locally available packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial`. After doing this, you can install the packages you need. Since `g++` and `gcc` have already been installed and are at their latest version, leave them alone.

But before installing the packages you need, purge the previous installs of the packages. Follow the following commands and even though they may appear counter intuitive, do not shorten the commands by removing the redundant seeming steps.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge libcups2-dev
sudo apt-get purge libcupsimage2-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage2-dev
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: The `purge` commands both result in an `unmet dependencies error`